# Doctrine Mongodb - Is it possible to declare a Document both as NORMAL and EMBEDDED

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating an app in Symfony with MongoDB as a backend, and I'm using Doctrine MongoDB connector which works fine. However, I have a situation where I have a Document (Normal Mongo document) and I want to use the same document as Embedded in another Document. I know I can copy the class and change the declaration but I'd hate to change everything on two places.
So is it possible to declare a Document as both Normal and Embedded?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use class inheritance to dish out two versions of the class with similar functionality coded into only one file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess`@DiscriminatorMap` annotation is what you want: more information:
[Doctrine Mapping](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)